# be highest or be the highest?

Tags: comparatives

I have these sentences:

1. "The unemployment rate was highest in the UK"
2. "The unemployment rate was the highest in the UK"

I would think the first one is correct. Is it true?

Do we have any situations when we use "be the highest"?

Answer (score 3):

Both are correct, but they generally mean different things.

1. *The unemployment rate was highest in the UK.*

   This is comparing the UK to other countries.
2. *The unemployment rate was the highest in the UK.*

   The primary purpose of including the article here is to compare rates within the UK: "The unemployment rate [in Runcorn] was the highest in the UK." It could be stretched to mean the same as (1), but **without context,** it doesn't mean that.

If your intention is to compare rates in the UK with rates elsewhere, use (1). If your intention is to compare rates within the UK, use (2).

[Englishgrammar](https://www.englishgrammar.org/superlatives/) has similar cases:

> *The* is not used with superlatives in predicative position, when we compare the same person or thing in different situations.
>
> - She works **best** in the mornings. (A woman’s work is being compared in different situations.)
> - She works **the best** in our team. (A woman is being compared with other members of the team.)

Comment: Thanks a lot! this is really helpful!